# Chrome <input> laggy only when wrapped in <form>

Tags: asp.net, html, google-chrome, forms

I have an ASP.NET webpage that is rendering many (~3000) `<input type="text">` textboxes on a single page (that are client-side only, i.e. do not need to postback). In Chrome, if these inputs are wrapped in `<form>` tags, Chrome will hang while I'm typing into the textboxes. (Duration is proportianal to how many textboxes are on the page). Firefox and IE do not have these problems.

You can view samples of my pages in the following links:

- Slow page (with `<form>`): http://jsfiddle.net/ZXcMs/
- Fast page (without `<form>`): http://jsfiddle.net/5V74U/1/

My questions:

1. Why is this? What exactly does `<form>` mean to a web browser?
2. My ASP.NET project requires the use of a `<form>` tag. How else can my site be made compatible with Chrome?

Comment: Have you considered another approach (with AJAX, or something,) that would reduce the need to have 3000 input fields on one page?

Comment: This webpage is replacing an Excel application. The UI of many textboxes is familiar. But to clarify, these textboxes are not going to need to be `POST`ed back, and the hangup is during client-side edit.

Comment: If you are doing a data table type of application, you might want to have all of those rows simply be listed in an HTML `<table>`... and then when a row item is to be edited, use jQuery (or JavaScript,) to actually add an input for that particular row item.  You might want to search for a "data table" or "grid" JavaScript plugin, here.

Comment: @Nathan I use the last chrome developer edition ver 19.0.1055.1 and its NOT hand to me.

Comment: I don't have any issue with Chrome 19.0.1049 with the "slow" one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nathan I just try the pages that you give and they **not hung at all** to me. I use the Chrome **version 19.0.1055.1**

**Now what I remember is that I have a similar issue and was because of an extension !**

Google Chrome is still developing and go from version 1 to 19 in one day :) and extensions are not so good tested with this version change. So extension that have been written just before some months maybe have problems now.

Disable all extensions to see if the problem goes away, and then if it does, just locate the one that have the issue.

Comment: Aha! I was running a version of 17, but the issue is gone when using version 19. Thanks much.